# Checking if a CSS property is supported by a tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my project I need to make sure if I can apply a particular CSS property to an HTML element. 
For example, I need to check if 'color' property is supported by 'img' tag.
   I remember reading somewhere that the code below could be used to check it.

```
 var image = document.createElement('img');
    if(image.style.color)
        image.style.color = "blue";
```

But this is returning wrong result. If someone knows how it is possible to check if a property is supported by an html element, then please answer.

Thanks.

Comment: no, it is not duplicate. those are about browser compatibility. This is about support for a particular tag. I need this in my project. Please dont close it

Comment: Any element can theoretically support any property, even if it may have no apparent effect or if it doesn't make sense intuitively. I don't think you can check this.

Comment: As a bit of trivia: `color` is a valid style property for the `img` element. If an image doesn't load, for accessibility reasons its `alt` attribute is often displayed instead. Most browsers will apply the `color` declaration to this text: http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/XsqJb/

Comment: Thanks @JamesDonnelly. That as helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know if a particoular property is present into an object you can do something like:

```
var image = document.createElement('img');
for (var key in image.style) {
    if (key == "color") image.style.key = "blue";
}
```

**Warning 1:** as said by others this check might have little sense, apart from particoular cases;

**Warning 2:** the upper code checks if the browser or the user has assigned a property to the object (eg. some browser like Webkit based do this for `style`, some other may not do it, like old IE).

Comment: It would be faster to do the chcek like this: if ("color" in image.style) {...}

Answer (score 4):

Literally, that code merely checks whether there is the property `color` on the element's native `style` object. It does not promise anything regarding the validity of such a property. Indeed, you could store any property on the object; whether or not it had a stylistic effect is another question.

JavaScript is not a teacher of CSS, and so it does not really have a mechanism for reporting whether or not applied styles were effectual. The nearest thing I can think of is to do some sort of iterative sweep over the element's [computed styles](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle) (but even then, you would need to supply that list of styles, i.e. tell it which to iterate over) and compare their values before and after the application of a given property.

This would be clunky, however, because the browser may report the style in a manner different from that in which you applied it. For example, you may have set a colour as HEX, but it may be reported out from the computed styles as RGB(a).

Comment: A very enlightening answer to the question. I was pondering over the same question for some time and came to the same conclusion.

Comment: hi, i dont need to check if the property is valid. I want to check if property applies to that tag.

Comment: In the context of CSS properties, isn't that the same thing? A style 'applies' to a tag in the sense that it does or does not cause a stylistic change to its appearance or behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

By CSS specifications, all properties can be set to all elements. They may not have a potential effect on an element (“apply to” it, to use CSS terminology, which is a bit odd), but this depends on other properties of the element. For example, `width` does not “apply to” a `span` element, but if you set `display: inline-block` on the element, `width` applies to it.

Moreover, e.g. the `color` property surely “applies to” an `img` element, but whether it *really* affects rendering is a different issue. It mostly does not, but if the image is not available, the `alt` text appears (or should appear) in the declared color.

So you should consider what you really need to know and why.